# Run Tomcat within Eclipse as a different user

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, permissions

I am running Eclipse Indigo EE on Windows 7, logged in as me.. I have Tomcat running within eclipse right now (under Servers view) but it's running under my user. I'd like to run it as a different user. How do I go about achieving that? I don't want to run it as a Windows service or outside of Eclipse, I want to continue to manage it through Eclipse which makes debugging, shutting down, starting up a lot simpler for me.

Any ideas how to go about setting that up or if it's even possible?

Thanks

Comment: On linux, the answer would be that it is difficult to do this without creating a security hole on your machine.

Comment: @StephenC, thanks but I have to use Windows unfortunately :)

Comment: Maybe you have a chance if you tweak into eclipse's run configurations and use Windows 7 `RUNAS` command... May I ask you for the reason why you need this feature, I can't even imagine for what it could be good for?

Comment: The reason is I have an SQL Server database that is configured to work with a specific domain user.... so I have to use domain authentication mode.  My Tomcat app uses SSO to login to the database, so I want Tomcat to be running under the same user. However, whomever is using eclipse to do the development doesn't have to be logged in as that user...

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to start the Tomcat server as a different user. Whereas you can achieve this by opening eclipse as a different user. Following are the steps for the same

1. Open command prompt.
2. Run following command with intended user name and eclipse exe's location

   runas /user:domainName\userName C:\eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\eclipse.exe

Thanks,
Sabeer